# Duplicate images with same id in Docker

Tags: docker

When I download the image with docker-compose file, the images are duplicated. 
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

   ubuntu:
      build: ./linux
      container_name: ubuntu
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
```

My Dockerfile in linux folder

```
FROM ubuntu
```

The output of the command "$docker images":

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              ccc7a11d65b1        9 days ago          120 MB
ubuntu_ubuntu       latest              ccc7a11d65b1        9 days ago          120 MB
```

Why this duplicity?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is Why this duplicity?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your Dockefile, you used `FROM ubuntu`, so you just inherited the image and did nothing out of it. So the new image is nothing but the same as `ubuntu` image. And that is why you are seeing the same id

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              ccc7a11d65b1        9 days ago          120 MB
ubuntu_ubuntu       latest              ccc7a11d65b1        9 days ago          120 MB
```

It doesn't mean you have `240MB` occupied from same two images. It just means that `ubuntu` and `ubuntu_ubuntu` point to the same image and that image size is `120 MB`.

You can do below

```
docker tag ubuntu ubuntu_my
```

And it will create another entry with that name and same ID and Size. Name and Tag are just reference to the ID. Multiple names can point to Same ID.

Comment: Don't create images or don't tag them. If you have already tagged by mistake, use `docker rmi ubuntu_my` to remove the duplicated tag

Comment: I found `docker rmi <name>` worked to remove duplicates, while `docker image rm <name>` failed. The second command worked with IDs (image ID column), but not names (repository column).