# Multiple docker images with same image_id

Tags: docker, memory-management

When I type `docker images` , I see multiple images with the same IMAGE_ID. Each of these images size is 1.1GB. My question is, do each of theses images actually take up 1.1GB? Or does docker use some sort of hashing based off of the image ID to ensure that duplicate images are not actually created?

```sh
$ docker images                                                                                  
REPOSITORY     TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dockertest1    latest               992b4d8867c4        52 minutes ago      1.1GB
dockertest2    latest               992b4d8867c4        52 minutes ago      1.1GB
```

Comment: `dockertest1` and  `dockertest2` are the same image, so only 1.1GB.

it's `docker tag` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is that dockertest1 and dockertest2 points to the same image that is 1.1GB of size. So only 1.1GB is used to store the image.

See [Duplicate images with same id in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779183/duplicate-images-with-same-id-in-docker) for more information.